# neo4j java node dynamic properties

Tags: neo4j, querydsl, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to create nodes of a specific type with properties which can be dynamic . 
For Example : I can create a Person node with name,age,address properties. But these need not be the only properties when I create another Person node. This node can have name,age,address and an additional property salary. Using spring data or query DSL needs me to create Java POJO class Person with fixed number of instance variables name,age and address .

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person {
@GraphId private Long id;

private String name;
private String age;
private String address;
}
```

I cannot add a dynamic property for salary for another Person node. Is there a way I can achieve this ?

Comment: but the attributes are optional, you don't have to set them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic properties are not supported in Neo4j-OGM at the moment (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-555)

If you only interact with your graph via the OGM and do not have to query on individual dynamic properties, you could try a Map of properties with a custom Converter, that converts this Map to a String (like json). The OGM will then use this converter to serialize the map to and from the graph.
Note that because the values are squashed into a String, it is now not trivial to query on an individual dynamic property.

To create a [custom converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_conversion-custom) you need to implement `org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.AttributeConverter` and provide the implementation to convert from a Map to String.
Then, annotate your map property in your domain entity like this:

```
 @Convert(MoneyConverter.class)
```

Edit:

As pointed out by Michael, if the salary is the only extra optional property, then it makes sense to have this property but set it only when it has a value. Dynamic properties are overkill in this case. You may want to use dynamic properties when you have an unknown and arbitrary set of properties to be persisted with the node

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please point me to an example for this custom converter ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try this. In fact the example I quoted had only salary as one extra field but the real use case is indeed with unknown and arbitrary set of properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround the limitations by creating a [CompositeAttributeConverter](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:type-conversion:custom) saving each dynamic property in the graph (not only as JSON-String wich cannot be queried well - as mentioned by luanne in the accepted answer)

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.*;

import org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.CompositeAttributeConverter;

public abstract class DynamicPropertiesConverter implements CompositeAttributeConverter<Map<String, ?>> {

    private Set<String> blacklist;

    public DynamicPropertiesConverter(Class<?> clazz) {
        blacklist = new HashSet<>();
        addAllFields(clazz);
    }
    public DynamicPropertiesConverter(Set<String> blacklist) {
        this.blacklist = blacklist;
    }

    public void addAllFields(Class<?> type) {
        for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields()) {
            blacklist.add(field.getName());
        }
        if (type.getSuperclass() != null) {
            addAllFields(type.getSuperclass());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ?> toGraphProperties(Map<String, ?> value) {
        Map<String, ?> result = new HashMap<>(value);
        result.keySet().removeAll(blacklist);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ?> toEntityAttribute(Map<String, ?> value) {
        return toGraphProperties(value);
    }
}
```

Now you can create a special version of this converter:

```
public class DynamicNodePropertiesConverter extends DynamicPropertiesConverter {
    public DynamicNodePropertiesConverter() {
        super(Node.class);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
import java.util.Map;

import DynamicNodePropertiesConverter;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.typeconversion.Convert;

@NodeEntity
public class Node {

    @Convert(DynamicNodePropertiesConverter.class)
    private Map<String, Object> data;

    /* getter and setter */
}
```