# Spring Data Neo4j 4 and dynamic properties

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

At my Neo4j/SDN 4 project I have a following entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Value extends BaseEntity {

    @Index(unique = false)
    private Object value;

    private String description;

...

}
```

During the application run-time I want to be able to add a new dynamic properties to `Value` node, like for example `value_en_US`, `value_fr_FR`.

Right now I don't know what exact properties will be added to a particular `Value` node during application run-time so I can't define these properties at the code as a separate fields in `Value`.

Is there at SDN 4 any mechanisms to define these properties during the application run-time? I need something similar to `DynamicProperties` from SDN 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such functionality in SDN 4, but it will be added in SDN 5 through a `@Properties` annotation on `Map`.

It will be available for testing in snapshot version very soon.
Check out [this commit](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/commit/e7b7b510c7f9ed75dc5adb72274d5d026727994c) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking forward to start porting my application to OGM3/SDN5

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at this response to a similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42632709/5249743

Just beware that in that answer the function:

```
public void addAllFields(Class<?> type) {
    for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields()) {
        blacklist.add(field.getName());
    }
    if (type.getSuperclass() != null) {
        addAllFields(type.getSuperclass());
    }
}
```

is not bullet proof.  For one thing it doesn't look at @Property annotations.  So if you want to go down that route keep your eyes open.

An 'improvement' is

```
public void addAllFields(Class<?> type) {
    for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields()) {
        blacklist.add(findName(field));
    }
    if (type.getSuperclass() != null) {
        addAllFields(type.getSuperclass());
    }
}

private String findName(Field field) {
    Property property = field.getAnnotation(Property.class);
    if(property == null || "".equals(property.name())) {
        return field.getName();
    } else {
        return property.name();
    }
}
```

But this obviously doesn't look for the annotation on methods...